# Show tables, describe tables equivalent in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to aws, can anyone tell me what are redshifts' equivalents to mysql commands?

```
show tables -- redshift command
describe table_name -- redshift command
```

Answer (score 125):

All the information can be found in a `PG_TABLE_DEF` table, [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html).

Listing all tables in a `public` schema (default) - `show tables` equivalent:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tablename
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
ORDER BY tablename;
```

Description of all the columns from a table called **table_name** - `describe table` equivalent:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE tablename = 'table_name'
AND schemaname = 'public';
```

---

Update:

As pointed by @Kishan Pandey 's answer, if you are looking for details of a schema different by `public`, you need to `set search_path to my_schema`. (`show search_path` display current search path)

Listing tables in `my_schema` schema:

```sql
set search_path to my_schema;
select * from pg_table_def;
```

Comment: Is there way to fetch default values set of respective columns ?

Comment: pg_table_def returns index also. safer to use `select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public'` instead.

Comment: is that in column order ?

Comment: see http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html for a bunch of simpler ways to extract column info, including order

Comment: Maybe they used work to at the time of this answer, but these queries don't return all tables anymore (2018-07-11). For example, I created my own schema and created a table in that schema, and the `pg_table_def` table doesn't have any information about that table. The query suggested by @j_c -- to query `information_schema` instead does work.

Comment: as pointed by @Kishan Pandey 's answer, if you are looking for details of a schema different by public, you need to `set search_path to my_schema` and consequently update the query to filter on `schemaname = 'my_schema'`

Comment: This did not show some tables that `\d+ <table name>` below did.

Comment: what about temp tables? I want to describe a temp table I created but temp tables cant be created with schema

Answer (score 89):

I had to select from the information schema to get details of my tables and columns; in case it helps anyone:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'; 

SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' AND table_name = 'mytable';
```

Comment: I am storing all our Segment SQL data to AWS Redshift, and so far this is the only solution I have come across that has worked for me!

Comment: I find this the superior method. The information_schema in Redshift is a superset of pg_table. Furthermore, pg_table_def seems to suffer from some kind of permission issue: while a schema/table will be in pg_tables, the corresponding information in pg_table_def will NOT be there. All I get is pg_catalog and public schemae. Frustrating.

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos To see your tables in `pg_table_def`, you must add the schema to your SEARCH_PATH: `SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user', public, YOUR_SCEHMA_NAME`. Definitely not intuitive...

Comment: @MarcoRoy Worth mentiong that, the `pg_table_def` is more informative as I see from the query results. `pg_table_def` shows whether the column is `distkey` or  `sortkey` and its encoding, which are not shown in the `information_schema.columns`. I guess that's where SQL clients like DataGrip gets the DDL from.

Answer (score 33):

Or simply:

`\dt` to show tables

`\d+ <table name>` to describe a table

Edit: Works using the psql command line client

Comment: This does not work for me .. it would work in Posgres but not Redshift .. better to go with Tomasz' answer.

Comment: I am accessing Redshift via SQLWorkbench (as recommended in the AWS getting started guide). If I try `\dt` I get `Error: Syntax error at or near "\"`. Are you accessing Redshift in some other way?

Comment: Yes, using psql command line client. I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually I didn't realise you could connect to Redshift with the psql client, but it is in the Amazon documentation. It's actually very useful. Thanks.

Comment: It shows slightly different information than Tomasz's solution. For example, \d+ tablename does not show sortkey information.

Answer (score 12):

Tomasz Tybulewicz answer is good way to go.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND schemaname = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME';
```

If schema name is not defined in search path , that query will show empty result.
Please first check search path by below code.

```
SHOW SEARCH_PATH
```

If schema name is not defined in search path , you can reset search path.

```
SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user', public, YOUR_SCEHMA_NAME
```

Comment: You may want to add the search path comment to Tomasz's answer.  I had this issue the first time I used the pg views and had to research it.

Comment: This is the correct solution concerned with `SEARCH_PATH`. But I only need to `set search_path to my_schema_name`.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift provides system tables and views which are simpler to use than the postgres default pg_catalog and information_schema tables. You can find the list of tables [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html)

To get list of tables in a schema, you can query SVV_ALL_TABLES / SVV_REDSHIFT_TABLES

```
    select * from SVV_REDSHIFT_TABLES where schema_name = '<<schema_name>>';
```

To get table definition including is sort key and distribution key, you can query SVV_REDSHIFT_COLUMNS

```
    select * from SVV_REDSHIFT_COLUMNS where schema_name = '<<schema_name>>' and table_name = '<<table_name>>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use - desc / to see the view/table definition in Redshift. I have been using Workbench/J as a SQL client for Redshift and it gives the definition in the Messages tab adjacent to Result tab.

Comment: thanks for that! Still missing a way of listing tables :/

Answer (score 1):

In the following post, I documented queries to retrieve TABLE and COLUMN comments from Redshift. 
https://sqlsylvia.wordpress.com/2017/04/29/redshift-comment-views-documenting-data/

Enjoy!

**Table Comments**

```
    SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS table_owner
     , c.relname AS table_name
     , CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'v' THEN 'view' ELSE 'table' END 
       AS table_type
     , d.description AS table_description
     FROM pg_class As c
     LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_description As d 
          ON (d.objoid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0)
     WHERE c.relkind IN('r', 'v') AND d.description > ''
     ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname ;
```

**Column Comments**

```
    SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS table_owner
     , c.relname AS table_name
     , a.attname AS column_name
     , d.description AS column_description
    FROM pg_class AS c
    INNER JOIN pg_attribute As a ON c.oid = a.attrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace
    LEFT JOIN pg_description As d 
     ON (d.objoid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = a.attnum)
    WHERE c.relkind IN('r', 'v')
     AND a.attname NOT         
     IN ('cmax', 'oid', 'cmin', 'deletexid', 'ctid', 'tableoid','xmax', 'xmin', 'insertxid')
    ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut

\d for show all tables

\d tablename to describe table

\? for more shortcuts for redshift

Answer (score 1):

redshift now support show table

```
show table analytics.dw_users
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=8641

Answer (score -7):

You can simply use the command below to describe a table.

```
desc table-name
```

or

```
desc schema-name.table-name
```