# Redshift column names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to redshift. I have some tables in 'abc' schema whose column names and primary key information needs to be extracted. Can someone guide.
Assume schema name is 'abc' and table name is 'xyz' whose columns are required to be listed in a single row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show tables, describe tables equivalent in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733385/show-tables-describe-tables-equivalent-in-redshift)

Comment: in Redshift - you know primary key is not enforced? and you also have distribution and sortkey which may be of interest.

Comment: correct answers are not marked in the link @Yankee.
I had visited that link but it didnt answer my question.
When i run the query id doesnt return my columns even after entering correct table name and schema name

Answer (score 0):

Use [v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql) provided by AWS Labs, you can use table level or schema level filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [SVV_COLUMNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_COLUMNS.html) table. It includes:

- Scheme Name
- Table Name
- Column Name

Answer (score 0):

I used this query to get a list of primary keys. A lot of additional info can be added. Postres official documentation to pg_ tables helps a lot.

```
SELECT
    f.attname AS column_name
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c ON
    n.oid = c.relnamespace
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute f ON
    c.oid = f.attrelid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint p ON
    p.conrelid = c.oid
    AND f.attnum = ANY (p.conkey)
WHERE
    n.nspname = 'schema_name'
    AND c.relkind = 'r'
    AND c.relname = 'table_name'
    AND p.contype = 'p'
    AND f.attnum > 0
ORDER BY
    f.attnum;
```